# After upgrade to 2.4.6 - Class Zend_Locale_Format (or Zend_Locale_Data) not found. What is the substitute?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.4.6

After upgrading to 2.4.6 I've got errors class not found.
Because Magento finally removed ZendFramework1 from codebase completely.

Which classes can replace missed ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are needed code under Magento framework:

1. `Zend_Locale_Format` -> `Magento\Framework\Locale\LocaleFormatter`.

e.g. `Zend_Locale_Format::toNumber` may be replaced with `(string) $this->localeFormatter->formatNumber()`

2. `Zend_Locale_Data::getList` -> `Magento\Framework\Locale\Format->getPriceFormat`